# Conditional row formatting LaTeX tables depending on selection in first column

Tags: tables, formatting, conditionals

Is there a way to highlight a specific row in table depending on the selection in first column. For example "HEA160" and this specific row turns red.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{lab01-data.csv}
    ID;h;b;tw;tf;r
    HEA100;96;100;5.0;8.0;12
    HEA120;114;120;5.0;8.0;12
    HEA140;133;140;5.5;8.5;12
    HEA160;152;160;6.0;9.0;15
    HEA180;171;180;6.0;9.5;15
    HEA200;190;200;6.5;10.0;18
    HEA220;210;220;7.0;11.0;18
    HEA240;230;240;7.5;12.0;21
    HEA260;250;260;7.5;12.5;24
    HEA280;270;280;8.0;13.0;24
    HEA300;290;300;8.5;14.0;27
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Section data}
        \label{tab:data}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        header=true,
        col sep=semicolon,
        use comma,
        columns={ID,h,b,tw,tf,r},
        columns/ID/.style ={string type},
        columns/h/.style  ={dec sep align, fixed zerofill, precision=2},
        columns/b/.style  ={dec sep align, fixed zerofill, precision=0},
        columns/tw/.style ={dec sep align, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
        columns/tf/.style ={dec sep align, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
        columns/r/.style  ={dec sep align, fixed zerofill, precision=2,column type/.add={}{@{}}},
        % <dec sep align> doubles column
        every head row/.style={
            output empty row,
            before row={
                \toprule
                % pay attention to column doubline due to <dec sep align>
                & % empty: first two columns
                \multicolumn{6}{l}{Dimensions} \\
                %
                \cmidrule(l){2-11}
                %
                \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{$Profile$}   &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$h$}         &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$b$}         &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{w}$}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{$t_{f}$}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$r$}      \\
                %
                \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
                %\cmidrule(lr){10-14}
                \cmidrule(l){10-11}
                %
                \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\si{}}    &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\si{mm}}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\si{mm}}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\si{mm}}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\si{mm}}     &
                \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\si{mm}}  \\
            },
            after row=\midrule,
        },
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        ]{lab01-data.csv}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Possibly, but probably easier to do it manually.  See `\pgfplotatablegetelem` (page 62).

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycolor}{m}
  { \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { HEA160 } { \rowcolor{red!15} } #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\mycolor}l<{\endcollectcell}}



\begin{NiceTabular} [colortbl-like]
  {
   E
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
   S[table-format=1.1]
   S[table-format=2.1]
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
  }
\toprule
\Block{3-1}{\emph{Profile}} & \Block[l]{1-5}{Dimensions} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
& {$h$} & {$b$} & {$t_w$} & {$t_f$} & {$r$} \\
& \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} \\
\midrule
    HEA100 & 96 & 100 & 5.0 & 8.0 & 12 \\
    HEA120 & 114 & 120 & 5.0 & 8.0 & 12 \\
    HEA140 & 133 & 140 & 5.5 & 8.5 & 12 \\
    HEA160 & 152 & 160 & 6.0 & 9.0 & 15 \\
    HEA180 & 171 & 180 & 6.0 & 9.5 & 15 \\
    HEA200 & 190 & 200 & 6.5 & 10.0 & 18 \\
    HEA220 & 210 & 220 & 7.0 & 11.0 & 18 \\
    HEA240 & 230 & 240 & 7.5 & 12.0 & 21 \\
    HEA260 & 250 & 260 & 7.5 & 12.5 & 24 \\
    HEA280 & 270 & 280 & 8.0 & 13.0 & 24 \\
    HEA300 & 290 & 300 & 8.5 & 14.0 & 27 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

---

If you want to read the data from a CSV file, here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` and the package `csvsimple` to read the CSV file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{lab01-data.csv}
ID;h;b;tw;tf;r
HEA100;96;100;5.0;8.0;12
HEA120;114;120;5.0;8.0;12
HEA140;133;140;5.5;8.5;12
HEA160;152;160;6.0;9.0;15
HEA180;171;180;6.0;9.5;15
HEA200;190;200;6.5;10.0;18
HEA220;210;220;7.0;11.0;18
HEA240;230;240;7.5;12.0;21
HEA260;250;260;7.5;12.5;24
HEA280;270;280;8.0;13.0;24
HEA300;290;300;8.5;14.0;27
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m}
  { \str_if_eq:VnT #1 { HEA160 } { \rowcolor{red!15} } #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{NiceTabular} [colortbl-like]
  {
   l
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
   S[table-format=1.1]
   S[table-format=2.1]
   S[table-format=3.2,minimum-decimal-digits=2]
  }
\toprule
\Block{3-1}{\emph{Profile}} & \Block[l]{1-5}{Dimensions} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
& {$h$} & {$b$} & {$t_w$} & {$t_f$} & {$r$} \\
& \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} & \unit{mm} \\
\midrule
\csvreader[head to column names, separator = semicolon]{lab01-data.csv}{}
  { \Test{\ID} & \h & \b & \tw & \tf & \r \\ }%
\\ \noalign{\vspace{-12pt}}
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thanks. But I want to import data from a csv file. Like in the example.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: That looks great. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason LaTeX editing tool Overleaf comes up with an Error:

l.36 ..._const:Nn \c__csvsim_package_expl_bool { 1 }
<<A number should have been here; I inserted '0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)>>

What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `csvsimple` and its version is bugged. But there is a solution. Go on the page for [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) on CTAN. Download the archive `csvsimple.zip`. Extract the file `csvsimple-l3.sty` and upload that file in your project on Overleaf.